# GNU linker error when linking to function in namespace

Tags: c++, linker, gnu

I'm trying to link my app with a static library that I've created. Though any global functions and class methods are linked with no problem, linking to functions declared in namespaces generate errors "undefined reference to [namespace]::function". Here is example:

include file contains:

```
void global_function (void);

namespace vm  
{  
void my_namespace_function (void);  
class some_class  
 {  
 static void my_class_function (void);  
 }  
};
```

cpp file contains this:

```
using namespace vm;

int main ()  
{  
global_function();      // this is fine  
some_class::my_class_function();      // this is fine  
my_namespace_function();   // "undefined reference to vm::my_classless_function()"  
return 0;  
}
```

And yes, I did check whether vm::my_namespace_function() is actually within a library.
Thanks for help.

Comment: So, **how** did you compile/link this code ? (this is important if you've forgotten to include a .o file, or are using static libraries and have the link order wrong)

Comment: How can `some_class::my_class_function();` be fine? Isn't that static private by default?

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement your functions in the same namespace as declared:

[file "namespace_func.cpp"]

```
#include    "namespace_func.h"
#include    <iostream>

void global_function( )
{
    std::cout << "global_function" << std::endl;
}

namespace vm
{
    void my_namespace_function( )
    {
        std::cout << "my_namespace_function" << std::endl;
    }

    void some_class::my_class_function( )
    {
        std::cout << "some_class::my_class_function" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

[file "namespace_func.h"]

```
#ifndef _NAMESPACE_FUNC_H
    #define _NAMESPACE_FUNC_H

void global_function( );

namespace vm
{
    void my_namespace_function( );
    class some_class
    {
    public:
        static void my_class_function( );
    };
};

#endif  // _NAMESPACE_FUNC_H
```

Then you can link to your "namespace_main.cpp":

```
#include    "namespace_func.h"

using namespace vm;

int main ( )
{
    global_function( );      // this is fine
    some_class::my_class_function( );      // this is fine
    my_namespace_function( );   // Fine. NO "undefined reference to vm::my_classless_function()"

    return 0;
}
```

Command line:

```
g++ -Wall namespace_main.cpp namespace_func.cpp -o namespace
```

The output is:

```
$ ./namespace 
global_function
some_class::my_class_function
my_namespace_function
```

- *note: you don't need to declare your functions to receive "( void )" as in "C". Just leave it empty.*

Answer (score -1):

How do you get a

```
 "undefined reference to vm::my_classless_function()"
```

when you call `my_namespace_function();`?

Did you check what you expect in library?

Comment: Ohhh, sorry all. nm on library shows namespace function is marked as undefined. I will have to figue why is that. Thank you all for prompt response.